# Why Google Page Speed Insights show different score everytime time I analyze the website?

Tags: google-pagespeed, google-pagespeed-insights-api

Why does Google Page Speed Insights show different score each time I analyze the website?
Why it shows different scores whenever I enter the my domain url as with([www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)) and without (.mydomain.com).
Also with([www.mydomain.com/index.html](http://www.mydomain.com/index.html)) and without index.html([www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the scores aren't too off.  Google uses a "synthetic" computer and mobile device when running your scores in the attempt to generate a real-world scenario.
If you want to run it on your own browser, you can:

1. Right click on your website
2. Select "Inspect"
3. A browser options area will display.  Within the top navigation of this area, click "Lighthouse".
4. You can then run a report on Speed, SEO..etc for both mobile and desktop.

Comment: They are usually VERY off. I ran my website and got a score of 82. Then I REMOVED some fonts, as my only change. Deployed it and the score want down to 64, from removing stuff! Then I ran it again and the score was now 84. This all happened within minutes. Site "hosted" through github pages if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because PageSpeed is based on two factors:

A) Data collected from Chrome users during the last 28 days.
B) Real-time data, this metric is influenced by your hosting and the user's connection, for example, which affects the metrics permanently.

PageSpeed is a tool to improve the usability and accessibility of your website, but it is not precise. You should use it as a guide and not as a rule.

Answer (score 0):

[PageSpeed Insights docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about) states the following

> Why do the field data and lab data sometimes contradict each other? 
>
> The field data is a historical report about how a particular URL has performed, and represents anonymized performance data from users in the real-world on a variety of devices and network conditions. The lab data is based on a simulated load of a page on a single device and fixed set of network conditions.

In there you can also find what device and network Lighthouse uses to simulate page load